# How to get this pointer from std::function?

Tags: c++, this, std-function, this-pointer

Since `std::function` can hold member functions, so it must store a pointer to the object instance somewhere.

How can I fetch the `this` pointer from a `std::function` that holds a member function?

Comment: Did you take a look at e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth. Of course I did. Tell me if I was blind to the answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this sort of information is deliberately not exposed in the library, and thus inaccessible in a portable way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An object of type `std::function` holds a **callable object**. A pointer to member function is a kind of callable object; it can be called with an argument of the appropriate class type, plus any additional arguments that it needs. For example:

```
struct S {
    void f(int);
};
std::function<void(S, int)> g(&S::f);
```

To call it, pass an object of type `S`:

```
S s;
g(s, 3);
```

Note that the `std::function` object does **not** hold an `S` object; it's only when you call it that the function pointer gets bound to an object.

Comment: My goal is to unwrap lambdas I passed as `std::function` to another function. How can I do so then? By unwrapping I mean to split it up into a `this` pointer and a static function pointer using `std::function::target` for further processing.

Comment: @danijar: Why don't you put your goal into your question instead? Your question makes little sense.

Comment: @danijar you can make your own function object which binds a `this` pointer and allows retrieval.

Comment: @danijar if it's a *static function*, there is no bound object instance.

Comment: When I store a lambda expression as `std::function`, it the `this` pointer already bound then?

Comment: @danijar - a lambda function doesn't necessarily have a `this` pointer. Whatever arguments it captures are stored in the object, and there is no mechanism for pulling them out. If you need to do that, a lambda is probably **not** what you should use.

Comment: @PeteBecker. Thanks, so the reference is kind of bound like `std::bind` would do, if I understand right. But why does `.target()` return a null pointer then?

Comment: @danijar - `std::function::target` is a template function; when you call it you have to specify the type that you're looking for. If that's the type stored in the object, you get back a pointer to the callable object. If it's not the right type you get back a null pointer.

Comment: @PeteBecker. The lambda comes as a parameter of the type `function<Handle<Value>(Arguments const &)>`. I try to cast that to a raw function pointer with the signature `Handle<Value>(Arguments const &)`. But, maybe because I used the capture clause, it returns a null pointer. But you answered the question, I asked. If you still want to help me, please follow the link I posted as comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the std::function template in a functionally similar template, but one that exposes the functions you want (like sorting by address or whatever else)

See [Stroika Function Template](https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/blob/a64703b0714a2b2642499eefeea15e4a15ce32f0/Library/Sources/Stroika/Foundation/Execution/Function.h) for an example implementation.

It works just like std::function (and lets you retrieve the aggregated std::function), but also keeps extra info to allow sorting and so on (handy to store the function pointers in a map and have object identity to later remove them).