# How to assign functor to function pointer?

Tags: c++, winapi, functional-programming, function-pointers, functor

Generally, can I assign a function object to a function pointer? I want to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    int num;
public:
    Foo(int num_par) : num(num_par) {}
    void operator()(int multiplier) {
        std::cout << multiplier * num << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    typedef void(*bar)(int);
    Foo f(42);
    bar b = f; // MSVC error
               // ^ C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'Foo' to 'bar'
    b(2); // wanted to print 84
}
```

If that's impossible, I’d like an alternative specifically for Windows programming, where I want `WindowProc` to contain state information that is set from data local to `WinMain`’s body (i.e. without making global variables). The problem occurs when assigning to the `WNDCLASSEX`’s `lpfnWndProc` member. Though `std::function` solves the problem for the above snippet:

```
std::function<void(int)> sf = f;
sf(2); // prints 84
```

it doesn't work for my WinAPI case:

```
class WindowProc {
    int some_state;
public:
    void set_some_state(int par);
    LRESULT CALLBACK operator()(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow) {

    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    WindowProc wp;

    typedef LRESULT(CALLBACK *baz)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

    std::function<baz> std_func = wp;
    std::function<baz> std_binded_func = std::bind(&WindowProc::operator(), &wp);

    // none of these compile:
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wp;                      // #1
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wp.operator();           // #2
    wc.lpfnWndProc = &WindowProc::operator(); // #3. Wrong anyway because some_state's value is part of the instance, not the class
    wc.lpfnWndProc = std_func;                // #4. Wrong anyway because some_state's value is part of the instance, not the class
    wc.lpfnWndProc = std_binded_func;         // #5

    // do stuff...
    wp.set_some_state(some_runtime_number);
    // ...do other stuff
}
```

MSVC 2013 Errors:

1.) error C2440: `=` : cannot convert from `WindowProc` to `WNDPROC`

2.) error C3867: `WindowProc::operator ()`: function call missing argument list; use `&WindowProc::operator ()` to create a pointer to member

2 cont.) error C2440: `=` : cannot convert from `LRESULT (__stdcall WindowProc::* )(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)` to `WNDPROC`

3.) same as '2 cont.'

4.) error C2440: `=` : cannot convert from `std::function<baz>` to `WNDPROC`

5.) same as 4.

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Use the spot for user data when you create the window and make something that accepts any callable object and provides that user data to it (e.g., have a class with a member function callback and a proxy one that retrieves the class instance to call that callback on, while that callback uses, say, a stored `std::function` to call the user's callback. You could probably technically skip the member function callback part). Something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2556/A-Simple-Win-Window-Wrapper-Class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, function objects contain additional context information besides the function to be called. About the only function object you can assigned to a function pointer is a lambda function with an empty capture but this is really just a function:

```
void (*bar)(int) = [](int x) { std::cout << x; }
```

If you want to get a function object through a function pointer, you need to hope that the function pointer has a suitable argument which is available for users to specify and which can passed through directly:

```
void call_function(int arg, void* user_data) {
    (*static_cast<std::function<void(int)>*>(userdata))(arg);
}
...

std::function<void(int)> function_object;
void (*bar)(int, void*) = &call_function;

bar(17, &function_object);
```

Most reasonably modern interfaces taking a function pointer also take a user-data pointer which can be used to pass through the necessary context. Obviously, in addition to passing through the necessary context it may be necessary to somehow maintain the life-time of object used as context.

I'm not a Windows programmer but I would guess that the API you are trying to use actually has the ability to set both a function pointer and a pointer to some user data. If there is no place to pass through context information you would need to somehow encode the necessary information in the function pointer itself. For example, you could use a function pointer which references a global object to get the context. Clearly, you would need a different function for each context you want to pass.

Comment: Yup, the last parameter of `CreateWindow` is a user data one, which can easily be retrieved later on.

Comment: All that parameter does is passes the user data to the windows's `WM_NCCREATE` and `WM_CREATE` message handlers. It does not actually assign the user data to the window. The message handlers have to do that separately, such as with `SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_USERDATA)` or `SetProp()` (either of which could also be called after `CreateWindow()` exits).  Other message handlers can then use `GetWondowLongPtr(GWL_USERDATA)` or `GetProp()` to retrieve the user data when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a pointer to a member function, in the usual way, then invoke it. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    int num;
public:
    Foo(int num_par) : num(num_par) {}
    void operator()(int multiplier) {
        std::cout << multiplier * num << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    typedef void(Foo::*bar)(int);
    Foo f(42);
    bar b = &Foo::operator(); // no more MSVC error
                              // ^ C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'Foo' to 'bar'
    (f.*b)(2); // wanted to print 84, and it does
}
```

You have to call it through an instantiation, in this example `f`.

Comment: Problem is the Windows API does not have any notion of member function pointers.

Comment: But cannot you use `C++` to program WinAPI? or is it strictly `C`-based?

Comment: You can use C++ all you want, but the interface is strictly C. With that in mind, none of these new-fangled function objects work unless you provide a layer between them and the API.

Comment: Ok, I believe you :) Although I don't really understand why cannot you wrap your desired functions inside `C++` classes/structs

Comment: You can as long as you give the the API what it expects: a plain old function pointer. Member function pointers are completely different types. Functors are also completely different types.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks. Basically you're saying that the callbacks etc cannot take function member pointers as parameters.

Comment: Yes, in this case, there is a `typedef LRESULT(CALLBACK *WNDPROC)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);` and inside `WNDCLASSEX`, a `WNDPROC lpfnWndProc;`. Only one thing fits that requirement, and it's a function with that signature (free, or static), or another if you count captureless lambdas that can convert to a function pointer, but they have the same limitations.