# Call function object from doIt function

Tags: c++, function-object

```
#include <iostream>
void hello1() {
    std::cout << "Hello from normal\n";
}
auto hello2 = [] {
    std::cout << "Hello from lamda\n";
};
class hello
{
public:
    hello() {}
    void operator()(std::string str) {
        std::cout << "From functor " << str << std::endl<<std::endl;
    }
};
void doIt(void(*f)()) {
    f();
}
int main() {
    hello1();
    hello2();
    hello hello3;
    hello3("Hello");    
    doIt(hello1);
    doIt(hello2);
    doIt(hello3); //How can I do this?
}
```

I just started learning function objects and I cannot call function object from doIt function
How can I call the last function object with doIt function?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is the call to `doIt(hello3)` coded differently than the other two?

Comment: Please add the exact error message you get for the line that's not working.

Comment: if [How to assign functor to function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795348/how-to-assign-functor-to-function-pointer) isn't a duplicate, it's really close.

Comment: Here's a better related answer: [passing functor as function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840029/passing-functor-as-function-pointer)